# Javascript Calc if 1 multiple by 2 for example

Tags: javascript, calculator

Hi I need help creating a javascript calculator. Unfortunately, I'm not even sure how to search for an answer so I thought I would start here.

I need a calculator that multiplies a number based on an input. For example

Gross income

Number of Children 1, 2, 3, etc

If 1 child multiply gross income by 20%
if 2 multiply gross income by 25%
if 3, etc.

And then obviously it spits out a value.

I would really appreciate some guidance on where to go to try something like this out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What difficulties did you encounter? What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var income = 100;
var children = 3;
var multiply = 0.15 + (children * 0.05);
var result = income*multiply;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you required, I'll give you only some guidances to get this done. Indeed, it's pretty basic and you won't need us to give you the whole code.

- Get the gross income value: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-form.phtml
- For the ratio, it depends on how you made the field:

  - Selectbox with `key => value` (for instance `1 => 0.20`, `2 => 0.25`): `ratio = value`
  - Textfield: `ratio = 0.15 + value * 0.05`
- Then, calculation: `result = ratio * grossIncome`

Answer (score -1):

```
var income = 100;
var children = 3;
var multiply = eval(0.15 + (children * 0.05));
var result = income*multiply;
```

use `eval()` for this,

If the argument is an expression, `eval()` evaluates the expression. If the argument is one or more JavaScript statements, `eval()` executes the statements.

Comment: Why would you do such a horrible thing? `eval()` is totaly unnecessary here, this is basically my code with an added security issue as every code injected into `children` would get executed by that `eval()`...